# Binary to strings as binary?

Tags: c#, .net, string, binary, arrays

[Redis keys are binary safe](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro). I'd like to mess around and put binary into redis using C#. My client of choice doesn't support writing binary keys it uses keys and it make sense. However i am just fooling around so tell me how i can do this.

How do i convert a raw byte[] into a string? At first i was thinking about converting a byte[] to a utf8 string however unicode has some checks to see if its valid or not. So raw binary should fail.

Actually i tried it out. Instead of failing i got a strange result. My main question is how do i convert a raw `byte[]` to the equivalent string? As in have the raw byte[] as a string and not encoding as base32/64/hex/whatever. My unimportant question is why did i get a 512 byte string instead of an exception saying this is not a valid UTF8 string?

code

```
var rainbow = new byte[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    rainbow[i] = (byte)i;
}
var sz = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rainbow);
var szarr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sz);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", ByteArraysEqual(szarr, rainbow), szarr.Length, rainbow.Length);
```

Output

> False 512 256

Comment: @dbaseman: No, i dont want to encode binary as text. I want the raw binary in the string struct. and now i edited a line...

Comment: I think the accepted answer is dangerously wrong... Also: if you are using BookSleeve, for info I spent a lot of time considering binary keys (BookSleeve uses the binary protocol, so it is trivial to do) - the problem was simply: I think the vast majority of users are going to be using string keys - not sure it is worth doubling the API to support both. There is a cheeky way I could support both on one API, but it would be a breaking change.

Comment: @MarcGravell you could but i'm not actually planning to do this. MAYBE in C for a specific problem but.... I'd have to do test to see if its worth it. It would have to be tons of keys before i consider it and i'd still want to test and i would still need to do prefixes (cant use bytesForId, need a byte or txt prefix for comment VS post VS some other id). I don't think its worth it unless you see a use in a major project. And like i said the only production project (i'm doing redis for fun tho) i can think of is in C, not C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use some kind of encoding to convert bytes to a string.  The encoding *iso-8859-1* will give the correct result:

```
var sz = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(rainbow);
var szarr = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(sz);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", ByteArraysEqual(szarr, rainbow), szarr.Length, rainbow.Length);
```

> True 256 256

The thing is that UTF8 requires more than one bytes per character.  It can encode the first 128 characters with one byte:

```
Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 127 })).Length);
```

> 1

But the rest require three bytes:

```
Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 128 })).Length);
```

> 3

So, when you convert bytes 0-255 to a string and back with UTF8, the first 128 come back as one byte, but the last 128 come back as 3.  128 + 3*128 = 512, hence your result.

ASCII doesn't know what to do with bytes past 128, so they just get encoded as `?`, and come back as one byte also.

Comment: The ascii encoding me false.... the last 128 was invalid. -edit- now you edited. Ok cool that makes some sense but i think it shouldn't try to convert invalid byte[] to utf8 and corrupt the byte[]. Which is why i thought an exception would be thrown.

Comment: @acidzombie24 ah right.  The first 128 will be equal, but all bytes after that will just be `? 63`

Comment: I figured it out. Encoding.Default is "iso-8859-1". var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); var sz = encoding.GetString(rainbow); var szarr = encoding.GetBytes(sz); works

Comment: This is actually using encoding decoding backwards: aka: don't do this. This *is not robust*.

Comment: Actually i accepted bc of my comment but i shouldnt until the answer is changed. ASCII is definitely wrong. I want to hear marc out before reaccepting tho

Comment: @acidzombie24 I corrected my answer for the record... I think your answer of using *DefaultEncoding* is correct.

Comment: Encoding.DefaultEncoding does not exist; Encoding.Default refers to the OS default code-page, and can be lots of different things - it is not 8859-1

Comment: lol, yes. Which is why i put `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");` in my comment. I remember skeet stories about the turkey test...

Comment: blah both you and marc are right. You answered the why utf8 is 3 bytes, marc answered why i shouldnt do this and i answered how to convert bytes into a string which is my actual question :x

Comment: Also thanks for the answer and the tip to lead me in the right direction

Comment: In my situation, when i use Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") it returns an encoding with code page 28591 which doesn't wotk, but `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` works fine!

Answer (score 9):

If you have an arbitrary byte[], the way to get that as a string is to convert it to something like hex or base-64. At the simplest:

```
byte[] key = ...
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
```

And in reverse:

```
key = Convert.FromBase64String();
```

It is *tempting* to use something like System.Text.Encoding, but that is entirely incorrect, and **cannot** be used to make a robust conversion. If you use Encoding, there are two problems:

- many keys cannot be successfully round-tripped
- many different byte[] keys could become the same string key

Both of these are bad! The problem is that the usage is backwards: an Encoding transforms an arbitrary string to/from a structured byte[], allowing to to encode/decode any string. Base-64 transforms an arbitrary byte[] to/from a structured string. Very subtle distinction, but hugely important.

Comment: What do you mean by `many keys cannot be successfully round-tripped`. I was thinking about testing with 16bit values but decided 0-255 is fine. I accepted stupidly forgetting the author didnt correct his `ASCII` solution. I accepted because of my comment and his explaining of why i got bytes (really .NET should have thrown :(). `many keys cannot be successfully round-tripped` could with my comment/solution i meant to accept and stupidly forgot he left the incorrect one up. Whats wrong with

Comment: `var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); var sz = encoding.GetString(rainbow); var szarr = encoding.GetBytes(sz);` iso-8859-1 is a 8bit encoder (it doesnt matter if its latin and i believe any other iso-8859-X encoding). It successfully converted 0-255 to the string and back. Redis handles binary keys so.. i dont see the problem except for forgetting to prefix the bytes with an identifier like tag, user, comment, etc. Also IMO base64 is not desirable if the container guartees its binary safe. Emails, websites etc do not guarantee this and is where i use base64 most of the time

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, especially the useful distinction between string representation of binary data (base 64) and binary representation of strings (encoding).  However, since *iso-8859-1* maps characters 1-256 one-to-one to their binary values, I think it should work for the scope of the Op's question ...?

Comment: Calling encoding.GetString is simply ***incorrect*** for an arbitrary byte[] - that only makes sense if the byte[] happens to contain string data encoded via that same encoding. As a consequence, calling GetString on an arbitrary byte[] can result in random strings that don't give back the original byte[] - or it could just throw an exception. Re the container being binary safe: well, *yes*, but that only matter if you are passing the **original** byte[] - in reality, the string-based key will already be UTF-8 encoded before going to redis. Honestly: calling GetString on an arbitrary set

Comment: `in reality, the string-based key will already be UTF-8 encoded before going to redis` wait what?!? Redis clearly states its binary safe. Why would it mess with my bytes? What changes the UTF8? client or something in redis itself? Also i understand what you mean by it being unsafe because it isnt the original encoding but i'm not using the encoding as a string, just a way to get my bytes into a string object. I also understand implementations may change however its iso so i dont think -this- implementation will change. Its using 8bits (more below)

Comment: without conversion messing around with the bits and thats what i require. UTF8 reserve bits and has invalid byte representations which i knew about and knew i couldnt use. This standard is written and wont change. It allows 8bits and wont mess around so i think its suitable for conversation as long as i dont except 0xAB to be represented as a specific char (which is why i said iso-8859-X will do, cyrillic would be just fine as well which is iso-8859-5)

Comment: @acidzombie24 "why would it mess with my bytes": because you clearly stated you are using a client that talks in terms of string keys. Redis keys are indeed binary, so the client will be transforming the string key into binary, and the obvious/typical way to to that is: UTF8. Remember: you *didnt give it bytes* - you gave it a string.

Comment: oh $%^&*( your right. So does your client convert ALL encoding (except utf8) to utf8 before sending? darn, this is making sense. I notice the key * was a bit strange but i didnt feel like looking into it as i only did this a few hours ago and had other things to do (i havent touch redis since i posted this question). I was concerned with pushing my bytes and using keys * to pull it again and converting it to my ORIGINAL buffer. So it IS sitting on redis as escaped utf8 bytes. I really should get a mercurial client on all my machines and check the source out

Comment: I rather like github and bitbucket as they allow getting the source in multiple archive formats of any branches.